# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader'

Tags: casting

I am trying to use a SqlDataReader to count the amount of categories I use.

Here is my Business Logic Code:

```
// Return count of main categories for homepage
    [DataObjectMethodAttribute(DataObjectMethodType.Select, false)]
    public int GetMainCatCount(int intCategoryID)
    {
        intCategoryID = SQLInject(intCategoryID);

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(intCategoryID) "
                        + "FROM  tblCategory "
                        + "WHERE intCategoryID=" + intCategoryID;
        con.Open();
        return (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
```

and here is my code in the code benhind page making the call:

```
public string CountCategory(int intCategoryID)
    {
        SqlDataReader myReader;
        myReader = CategoryBLL.GetMainCatCount(intCategoryID);

        myReader.Close();
        myReader.Dispose();
        return Convert.ToInt32(myReader);
    }
```

I want to use the results of the SqlDataReader to populate a label tag. When I try and run this code I recieve this error message:

**Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader'**

Could anyone please tell me where I am going wrong.
Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could anyone please tell me where I am going wrong. Thanks...

Sure: you're going wrong trying to convert an int to an `SqlDataReader`. You're also trying to convert an `SqlDataReader` to an int, later on.

Honestly, the types in your example are so screwed up that I can't even figure out what the code is supposed to do. To get started, [read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx).

---

Thinking more about it, here's a potential fixed version:

```
public string CountCategory(int intCategoryID)
{
    int count = CategoryBLL.GetMainCatCount(intCategoryID);
    return count.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "GetMainCatCount" method returns an int, but you're assigning its return value to a variable of type SqlDataReader:

```
SqlDataReader myReader;
myReader = CategoryBLL.GetMainCatCount(intCategoryID);
```

Additionally, your CountCategory method is defined as returning a string, yet you're returning an Int32 from it (the result of a Convert.ToInt32 call on the last line).

Comment: So I should change it to:
public int CountCategory(int intCategoryID)
{
}

Also How would change it to not be a return type of SqlDataReader?

Comment: Check out @John Millikin's code above. If you want to return an int from CountCategory, then just use "return CategoryBLL.GetMainCatCount(intCategoryID);".

Answer (score 0):

```
 myReader = CategoryBLL.GetMainCatCount(intCategoryID);
```

In that line, you're trying to convert an Int32 to an object of Type SqlDataReader.

You want to try `myReader.GetMainCatCount(intCatagorID);`

Comment: Other way around: he's trying to convert Int to SqlDataReader.

Comment: Whoops you're right. My post originally was commenting on " return Convert.ToInt32(myReader);" which converts SqlDataReader;